# Running dynamic sql based on values in a table, and then appending them to the same result set

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I have a table I need to query named "customData".
The table contains three columns (relevant ones).  One contains a field and the other a table name and the third has the id of the record in the foreign table.  The goal is to take those values, look up the value for that field in that foreign table, and append it as a column in the result set.  Is this even possible?  I can not wrap my head around a way to build the dynamic sql using data from the table if the table isn't read yet.

I'm trying to fix an incredibly slow lookup currently happening in a notmapped field by turning this into a stored procedure.

```
ID  Value  foreignTable ftIndex ftRow   customField 
1  "yes"  "tblDriver"    2001    "Name"  "Licensed?"  
2  "no"   "tblDriver"    2002    "Name"  "Licensed?"
3  "7"    "tblOrigin"    1131    "Name"  "tank count"
```

expected output:

```
1 "licensed" "yes" 'Darryl Coffman'
2 "licensed" "no"  'Cash Rainer'
3 "tank count" "7"   'texas field'
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would clarify what you want to do.

Comment: This sounds like you have a major design flaw, if I am honest, and your real focus should be fixing it.

Comment: A stored procedure isn't going to speed it up, either; the design is the issue. The only thing that us going to speed this up is fixing the design and normalising it.

Comment: i added the example data.  Lamu, i am just the guy tasked with making it work.  We have these tables that contain data for every field in every table (besides themselves) because they are used in our audit-trail.  However "custom data" functionality was also shoe-horned into the same tables later to allow someone to append custom values to a table, which many clients do using a spreadsheet import.  I don't have a thousand hours to redesign something hundreds of people are already using.

Comment: So are you only after rows where `foreignTable` has a value of `'tbl_Driver'` and `ftRow` a value of `'Name'`? If so, then you don't need dynamic SQL. If not, then provide a more comprehensive sample data, and we can show you how you can start fixing your design.

Comment: it's more of an issue of where we are currently reading it from (a notmapped field that references a virtual model).  Tracing it while the page is loading (which takes about ten minutes) shows that the notmapped field is tanking the system.  It's ran on every row of the table, multiple times due to some stupid design decisions in the save function.

Comment: and no i'm not just after that data.  The page i'm trying to fix allows you to reference any table in the database and attach custom data to it.

Comment: The fact that you are mixing data types makes this worse, unfortunately. I stand by my statement, you need to take a step back, and then go down the (long) path of fixing the design and normalising it. That'll solve all the scaling and performance issues you have. It will not be a quick fix, but it will fix the problems you have.

Comment: well they are all stored as strings actually.

Comment: If every column in your database really is an `(n)varchar` then you ***really*** need to go back to the start and redesign the entire thing. `(n)varchar` is *not* a "one size fits all" datatype. Your design is severely flawed, far more than I thought. There really is only one solution; fx that design. I wish you luck with it, and if you get stuck with parts, then do ask questions on the specific parts you're stuck on; the community will be happy to try and help you and push you in the right direction , or show you where you've gone wrong.

Comment: no i was saying the custom data is stored as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this doesn't specifically answer the question, I wanted to summarise my above comments into an answer to show why the design you have is so flawed, and why it isn't going to work; and therefore why you need to fix it. *Note that we do not have enough information to suggest what that fix is, other than to state that you need to spend a considerable time fixing the design into a normalised approach.*

Firstly, the only way you can achieve the final goal you are after is with dynamic SQL. If you were only after a single columns value, then you would actually be "ok", as you could write a statement like this:

```sql
SELECT DT.ID,
       DT.CustomField,
       DT.[Value],
       D.[Name]
FROM dbo.DenormalisedTable DT
     JOIN dbo.tblDriver D ON DT.ForeignTable = N'tblDriver'
                         AND DT.ftIndex = D.ID
WHERE DT.ftRow = N'Name';
```

Unfortunately, you go on to state that that isn't the case, meaning that you would need a query like the below (for the 2 sample tables we have):

```sql
SELECT DT.ID,
       DT.CustomField,
       DT.[Value],
       CASE DT.ForeignTable WHEN N'tblDriver' THEN CASE DT.CustomField WHEN N'Name' THEN D.[Name] END
                            WHEN N'tblOrigin' THEN CASE DT.CustomField WHEN N'Name' THEN O.[Name] END
       END
FROM dbo.DenormalisedTable DT
     LEFT JOIN dbo.tblDriver D ON DT.ForeignTable = N'tblDriver'
                              AND DT.ftIndex = D.ID
     LEFT JOIN dbo.tblOrigin O ON DT.ForeignTable = N'tblOrigin'
                              AND DT.ftIndex = O.ID;
```

Obviously, however, it have lots of other tables, and very likely other columns (not just a `name` column) to dynamically get the values of. So you end up with a something awful like this:

```
SELECT DT.ID,
       DT.CustomField,
       DT.[Value],
       CASE DT.ForeignTable WHEN N'tblDriver' THEN CASE DT.CustomField WHEN N'Name' THEN D.[Name]
                                                                       WHEN N'Age' THEN D.Age
                                                                       WHEN N'Dob' THEN D.Dob
                                                   END
                            WHEN N'tblOrigin' THEN CASE DT.CustomField WHEN N'Name' THEN D.[Name]
                                                                       WHEN N'Age' THEN D.Age
                                                                       WHEN N'Dob' THEN D.Dob
                                                   END
                            WHEN ... --20 more WHENs, 50? Plus all the inner CASE expressions
                            WHEN N'tblOwner' THEN CASE DT.CustomField WHEN N'FirstTraded' THEN Onr.FirstTraded
                                                                      ...
                                                  END
       END AS ColumnValue
FROM dbo.DenormalisedTable DT
     LEFT JOIN dbo.tblDriver D ON DT.ForeignTable = N'tblDriver'
                              AND DT.ftIndex = D.ID
     LEFT JOIN dbo.tblOrigin O ON DT.ForeignTable = N'tblOrigin'
                              AND DT.ftIndex = O.ID
     LEFT JOIN ...
     ---20 more JOINs, 50?
     LEFT JOIN dbo.tblOwner Onr ON DT.ForeignTable = N'tblOwner'
                               AND DT.ftIndex = Onr.ID;
```

This, however, has some major problems. The first would be implicit conversions of data types

For example notice that I have the columns `Name`, `Age`, and `Dob` here. These choices were intentional as there are all completely different types of data; string, numerical, and date & time respectively. If a `CASE` expression returns different data types then [Data Type Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) will be used to determine the returned data type. This is very likely going to end up with a date and time data type, meaning that your numerical and/or `(n)varchar` columns are going to fail the statement due to conversion errors. This means that the above fails. Though you *could* `CONVERT` every expression returned in the `THEN`s, that severely effects the data and could easily result in the data be consumable or not being displayed as you want.

This issue also applies to the `ON` clauses, which **assumes** that every `ID` column is the same data type (`int`?), as having different data types will completely break this. If they aren't, then you would need to use a `TRY_CONVERT` to the appropriate data type, which brings us onto the next point: **Performance**.

Performance will be ***awful***. Let's not beat around the bush. A query like this is not going to perform well due to the sheer number of reads needed of different tables. You'll be lucky this returns data in minutes, perhaps hours, depending on how large your database is. Adding something like a `TRY_CONVERT` in the `ON` ruins any (slim) chance that the RDBMS could have made use of an index for a seek.

Finally, we have scalability. Writing the above would be a task unto itself, which means you would *have* to use dynamic SQL. But the problem you are trying to solve here is the performance issue, and I've also told you, this solution is going to be **slow**, and I *mean* **slow**. A dynamic statement isn't going to improve that, and the considerations you would need to even get the statement to work in the first place would not be small; so let's not even go down that path, as it's already thrown out the window.

So, the only solution here, to get a performant query, is fix your design. Normalise your data, and don't store information like where the lookup table is in a table. Designs like this, although might "look" intuitive to a user, do **not** scale, and do **not** perform well. Such designs normally come from looking at an RDBMS like it's a programming language, and applying the same logic. SQL isn't a programming language, and it doesn't work like one; what it excels at and what it struggles at are completely different.

---

TL;DR: The design you have in effect is the reason why your query is slow. You cannot get around that as the query you have (what ever it is) is not the root cause. Only fixing the design will fix the performance problem, and that is where you are going to need to focus significant time and resources to fix.

Comment: i appreciate your time and effort.  The particular problem i am facing i "seem" to have solved by rewriting the update function.  There was no conceivable reason to requery the database when saving.  The validity checks even with an invalid model state were being passed through the grid's read function (it's a telerik grid).  Preventing that has improved performance enormously.  It takes maybe ten seconds to load the grid initially but every time it was passing through another function the models are re-created, re-running a dbquery on every row.  Stopping this fixed my slowdown.  Thank you.